# Dropdownlist with 2 columns in c#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have a website build using MVC and .Net with EF6. I want in a view to show a dropdownlist with the name and surname of a class.

How can I do this?

My code is:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("ShiftManagerId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

And the class is:

```
public class ShiftCalendar
  {
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ShiftId { get; set; }
    public virtual Shift Shift { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public DateTime ShiftEndTime { get; set; }        

    public User ShiftManager { get; set; }
    public string ShiftManagerId { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

In your ShiftCalendar class add:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ShiftManagersList
{
    get {  var managers = dbContext.ShiftManagers.Select(f => new SelectListItem
                                           {
                                               Value = f.Id.ToString(),
                                               Text = $"{f.Name} {f.Surname}"           
                                          });
          return managers;
        }
}
```

Then in your view try something like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ShiftManagerId, Model.ShiftManagersList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Please keep in mind, I don't know the exact name of your dbContext and User Property names. So change the code accordingly.